# Confused on the definitions of norm of a function.

Tags: metric-spaces

If   $$\|f \| =\sup \{|f(x)|:x \in [0,1]\} $$
and also $$ \|f \|=\int^1_0 |f(x)| \, dx,$$
then for $f(x)=x$, we have $\sup \{|f(x)|:x \in [0,1]\} = 1$.
But $\int^1_0 |f (x)| \, dx = \int^1_0 |x| \, dx= \frac{1}{2}$.
Then how is it possible ?

Comment: They are two different norms. More precisely, one should write $\|f\|_\infty$ and $\|f\|_1$ for the two.

Comment: This is just like defining a metric space with different metrics.  You can equip the real line $\mathbb{R}$ with the normal Euclidean metric, i.e., $ d(x,y) = |x - y| $, or, maybe, with the discrete metric, i.e., $d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & x = y \\ 1 & x \neq y \end{cases}$.  With the Euclidean metric, $d(\frac{1}{2}, 1) = \frac{1}{2}$, while with the discrete metric, $d(\frac{1}{2}, 1) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector space can be associated with different norms, all satisfying norm axioms. In your example, the first is $L^\infty$ norm and the second $L^1$ norm.